# How can I get specific items in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

How can I get selected items in listview, I have listview with arrayadapter, the listview contains 26 items but I need to show only 6 items, another items shown in the show more button. How can I get this.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.....!

**MainActivity.java**

public class SelectProtocolActivity extends Activity {

```
ListView listview;
ListViewArrayAdapter arrayadapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.protocol_list_view);
db = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(getApplicationContext());
        protocols = db.getAllProtocolsList();
        arrayadapter = new ListViewArrayAdapter(this, protocols);
        listview.setAdapter(arrayadapter);





listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id){

        }
        });
    }
```

}

**ListViewArrayAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {

    private final Activity activity;
    private final List<Item> itemList;

    ProtocolArrayAdapter(Activity activity, List<Items> itemList) {
        assert activity != null;
        assert protocolList != null;

        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (null == itemList)
            return 0;
        else
            return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Item getItem(int position) {
        if (null == itemList)
            return null;
        else
            return itemList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        //Protocol protocol = getItem(position);

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_list_item, null);

        TextView tvItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

        Item item = getItem(position);
        if (null != item) {
            try {
                tvItemName.setText(item.getName());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just added hardcoded size for items

Comment: Thats absolutely fine but what all links are you referring to.. just to know what have you accomplished til now... still you can get some idea here http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

Answer (score 0):

please read carefully hope description  help  you

Hi there is many way two achieve that thing you  can use expandable list view here or

I thought you make Bean class for that add one more Boolean variable name(isOpen).
by default there value is false
apply  click event on see more button 
Design Row item XML according to that

6 item in separated  layout and 20 in separated.

20 Item layout visibility by default GONE

than in your list view click on see more according to position set isOpen = true
and notifydata set change.

and parametrically set in adapter is isOpen=true  your 20 item layout is VISIBLE other vice gone

Comment: yes I can help you but now i am busy please in my work but when ever i am free i defiantly help you  can you put your code here what have you done for that

Comment: ad please specify me you need to show more item in list view or you are taking about item of item